# Can I auto-forward my Gmail to another address?

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I'm kind of paranoid about my email and I don't want it to be on Google's servers only. Especially after my account got hacked and all my email got deleted.

So I would like to auto-forward my Gmail to another address, but are there any settings I have to enable?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Gmail: **Settings** → **Forwarding and POP/IMAP** → **Forward a copy of incoming mail to...**