# How can I change my Gmail address?

Tags: gmail, google-account

How can my wife explain to gmail that her name changed when we got married?

There does not seem to be a way to change my wife’s Gmail’s email address to use my surname.

Whatever I try her now incorrect gmail address is in the “senders” header and some email clients display the value of the “sender” header rather than the “from” header.

Comment: you cannot change an email address. Are you talking about the display name ?

Comment: @phwd, her email address is FirstName.OldLastName@gmail.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot change an email address, you can change the display info, create a new account and/or add a second account.

> It isn't possible to change your
>   username once you've created an
>   address, but there are some options to
>   change the way your username is
>   [displayed](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8158).

The three ways to <strike>do what I think you are trying to achieve (change in the display name)</strike>  at least change how the display name appears

1. Changing the profile information in her [Google Profile](http://www.google.com/profiles/me/editprofile?edit=b) .
   <sub>This will affect all Google products.</sub>
2. Changing it in her [Google Account](https://www.google.com/accounts/EditUserInfo)
3. Gmail specific under `Settings`->`Accounts and Import`, edit info for all or just her default email address. Switch the option from (your name in Google accounts) to the desired display name.

**Edit, saw your updates** : Try creating a second account and use the Import option to get mail from her old address.

**Update** : Use the above settings for the display name. Import the new account `FirstName.NewLastName@gmail.com` to the old account. Then in your `Account and Import` settings choose `FirstName.NewLastName@gmail.com` as the default address to send mail as. Also switch this to enabled as well

> Always reply from default address
>   (currently
>   FirstName.NewLastName@gmail.com)

This way

- Recipients see the new address
- She will always reply from her new address
- Labels are maintained as the old account is being used.

From here you can slowly make the transition from the old address to the new address since she has over 30 labels.

Comment: You could also add the option to forward the old email to the new one in your list.. :)

Comment: but we don't wish to loose all the lable and the last time I tried to inport email (with pop) gmail lost all the lables

Comment: @Ian:  See the link in my answer.  It discusses the label issue you mentioned.

Comment: If the labels were done by hand (manually) , then that would be an arduous task. How many labels do you have ?

Comment: @phwd, There are close to 30 or 40 lables as the account has been in use for a long time.

Comment: I added a migration method which uses the old account as the base storage but the new address as the default sender. It will be a slow migration but I believe it should work.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the benefit of this.  You'd have to log in under the old account in order to search it.

Comment: @rchern Yip that is the basic idea, to continue to use the old account but have the new address as the reply to address. It seems that label migration (30-40 manual,no filter, labels) would be hard unless it is taken in small steps. So for the time being at least she is able to use the old account but have the display name and email address she wants in From field. Then later on the full move can be made to the new account.

Comment: Why would you want to do that though?  Is there something I'm missing about the link I posted and it's discussion and suggestions on transferring labels?  I haven't tried it personally, but it says it works.  Do you have personal experience that it doesn't?

Comment: @rchern I see nothing wrong/missing with the link I think it is very useful (IMAP tends to be more stable than POP, as well as the two connection). I am just suggesting to use the old account, assuming that the messages that are labelled are too many for folder transfer via IMAP . I have not tried that process myself as I sync between my mail client and my iPhone . I am mainly trying to avoid the transfer of messages since the majority is already stored on the old account. If it were me I would start here and then follow-up with your solution in small batches for the migration.

Comment: Just seems like having messages in 2 places is not what the OP wanted.  But, I'm not the OP, so not sure!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [custom "From" address](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370). And if you set it up to use gmail's SMTP, only the new address will be included in outgoing emails, with no reference to the old.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the email address, only the display name as mentioned.  It sounds like this isn't what you want though - you want a completely new Google Account.

You would need to create the new account and then move the data, email and other Google services, over into the  new account (see below)

On the old email, you could then add an auto-responder letting people know to use the new email, forward mail from the old account into the new one, or have the new email account check the old email account.

Archived info from `http://knol.google.com/k/changing-your-gmail-username-or-email-address`

> It is not possible to change your username in gmail. The username is
>   chosen at the time the account is created and is the permanent
>   identifier of the account.
>
> But if you need to use a different username, it is possible. You
>   simply need to create a new account and move your content over from
>   the old account. Here's how.
>
> Step 1: Create a new account You should sign out from your existing
>   account and then choose [Create an account](http://mail.google.com/mail/signup) from the gmail login screen.
>
> Step 2: Grab your mail from the old account Login to the new account
>   you just created, go to the settings link in the top right, and choose
>   the [Accounts and Import](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/accounts) tab. Gmail doesn't let you use its standard
>   import feature to transfer from one account to another, so you'll need
>   to use the Check mail using POP3 entry. Enter the following
>   configuration:
>
> Username: Your old gmail email address Password: Password for your old
>   gmail account POP server: pop.gmail.com Port: 995 Always use secure
>   connection: checked Label incoming messages: checked
>
> This will pull over all your old mail and will continue to pull over
>   new mail received at the old account until you disable it. It will
>   not, however, save any label information. You will need to relabel
>   your emails (or simply rely on gmail's search features to find
>   messages).
>
> If you absolutely need the old label structure, the only solution is
>   to use an [IMAP client](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75725) to connect to both the old and new account and
>   copy over folders/labels. But this solution can be tricky, because you
>   can only copy over a certain ([unspecified](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81312)) amount of mail at a time.
>   The non-Google program Gmail Backup might be able to assist with this
>   process, but I can't vouch for its effectiveness.
>
> Step 3: Export and import your contacts Login to the old account and
>   follow the instructions on the [Export Gmail contacts](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=24911) page. Remember
>   the location of the saved file.
>
> Login to the new account and follow the instructions on the [Importing
>   CSV files](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14024) page using the file you just saved.
>
> Step 4: Export and import your filters If you have many filters on the
>   old account, you can use the [Filter import/export](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/03/new-in-labs-filter-importexport.html) feature of gmail
>   labs to bring them to your new account.
>
> Step 5: Non-Gmail Google account contents If you have other content in
>   your Google account that you want to transfer (calendars, documents,
>   photos, etc), you'll have to do this separately. The [Data Liberation
>   Front website](http://www.dataliberation.org/) has detailed information on how to export and import
>   data from pretty-much every Google product.