# How do I change my Gmail ID without changing to a new account?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change my Gmail address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/how-can-i-change-my-gmail-address)

Is there a way to change my Gmail ID?

I want everything else to remain the same, and to just change the name of the email ID.

Is that possible? If not then is there another alternative which will have do the same effect?

Comment: Can you clarify please? What you want to do is change `some.email@gmail.com` to `this.other.email@gmail.com`, without changing any other information and retaining your accumulated messages?

Comment: @Al Everett Exactly as you say.

Answer (score 5):

From [Google's Help](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=8158):

> It isn't possible to change your username once you've created an address [...]

Your best bet is to create a new Gmail account and set up mail forwarding from your old account to the new one. You could set up your old address as a POP3 account on your new one (under Mail Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP) and retrieve existing mail messages. There is no way to automatically migrate other settings either, but you can recreate them manually.

Comment: What about labels and stars? Through POP, will those be transferred as well?

Comment: @TestSubject528491 No. POP is [a standard protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) that doesn't know anything about Gmail's labels and stars.

Answer (score 1):

The following possibilities exist:

[You can have different usernames and get emails from other Gmail accounts into your main Gmail account](http://news.cnet.com/how-to-use-gmails-multiple-inboxes-for-extra-gmail-accounts/)

*[GMail lets you create infinite number of aliases](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/09/gmail-easter-eggs-dot-blindess-email.html). An email sent to paris.hilton@gmail.com or paris.hilton+fans@gmail.com or paris.hilton+blog@gmail.com will all be redirected to one common email address and that is paris.hilton@gmail.com.
Gmail does not recognize characters after the PLUS symbol but the gmail search filter can distinguish between the different address and you can therefore redirect these email to separats gmail folders or apply different labels.*

Gmail doesn't [recognize dots as characters within usernames](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?ctx=gmail&hl=en&answer=10313), adding or removing dots from a Gmail address won’t change the actual destination address. You can add any number of dots to your existing address or capitalize any of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

First You should create new gmail account and park it in your old account .
Mail Settings -> Accounts and Imports