# How do I change my Gmail ID without changing to a new account? Change my Gmail sender address from firstname.lastname to

Tags: gmail

How do I change my Gmail ID without changing to a new account?

Comment: Related: [Can I change my Gmail email address?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/93/can-i-change-my-gmail-email-address?rq=1)

Comment: "To" what? You seem to be missing some information here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do so.   Google do not provide support for this.

If you really want it changed, set up a new Google account, and migrate your old account to it.