# Change or add email address to Google account

Tags: google-account, account-management

My primary email address is going to be invalid soon. So I want to change my email address for my Google account. However, it seems that I can't change my email address and I can't even add a new email address. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: On a [recent comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76649/change-or-add-email-address-to-google-account/118231?noredirect=1#comment106407_118231) to another answer, the OP mentioned that their domain is gulli.com, a German domain. According to Wikipedia, on May 2018 the domain was sold.

---

The email addresses of Google Apps accounts, including those of Google Apps for ISP, can't be changed by the user, only by the organization administrators. They should have access to the administration panel for your organization by signing into http://admin.google.com.

It's worth to say that when the original revision of this answer was posted it was not possible to change the primary domain of an organization [1], so if the domain will be invalid soon, then the organization information (the information of all the organization accounts) should be migrated. For details about how to migrate Google Apps information go to [Migrate data away from Google Apps - Google Apps Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/100458?hl=en).

Nowadays G Suite allows to change the main domain. For details see [Change your primary domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7009324?hl=en)

**Notes:**

[1][Change your primary domain - Google Apps Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/54819?hl=en)

Related

- [Google Apps for ISP EOL](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/_zgHXEBjwKU)
- [Gulli.com](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulli.com) (Wikipedia in German)

Comment: What is the best way to get in touch with the organization administrator?

Comment: Go to https://www.google.com/accounts/ForgotPasswd, select I forgot my password, in the box that will showup write your email address and click next. The following screen could show you how to contact the corresponding organization administrators if the set that information. The alternative is to ask for help to the IT support department of your organization.

Comment: When I do that, it says `Please contact your domain IT administrator to reset your password or retrieve your username.`. There are no contact information given. With "your organization", do you mean the Google Support of the country I live in? Just to be clear.

Comment: If someone gave you your username and password to access the account for first time they could be "your domain IT administrator". If you did the initial registration then you are the "your domain IT administrator".

Comment: It's my private Google account. I don't think we're talking about the same thing. I don't have a Google Apps account, just a regular Google account (GMail, PlayStore, ...).

Answer (score 0):

On my previous answer the OP posted a comment saying

> It's my private Google account. I don't think we're talking about the same thing. I don't have a Google Apps account, just a regular Google account (GMail, PlayStore, ...)

I understand that they means that the primary email address has a gmail.com or googlemail.com domain. In this case the only way to change the primary email address is to remove Gmail from the account then adding it again is you still want to use Gmail, otherwise you could have your Google account with a third party email address.

Reference

- [Change the email address for your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/19870?hl=en) (Official help article)
- [Can I change my Gmail email address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/93/88163) (Q&A on this site)

Comment: It was neither a gmail.com nor googlemail.com domain, it was a German domain called gulli.com.

Comment: I forgot your previous message `Please contact your domain IT administrator to reset your password or retrieve your username.` That means that you had a Google Apps account. At this time gulli.com redirects me to a page on `sdsjweb.com`. Is gulli.com still working for you?