# Autoforward outgoing mail in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send a copy of outbound messages to another address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/send-a-copy-of-outbound-messages-to-another-address)

Is there a way to make all mail sent through a Gmail account get Auto BCC'd to another address?

Here is my scenario:

I have a client running there emails on Google apps with there own hosted domain.
One lady handles incoming mail queries from there website.

There is a rule set on her email address that all incoming mail gets copied to a central address so everyone is updated with queries and can follow up or take over at any point.
This lady then replies and we want a copy of her reply to be sent to this central address so everyone knows the query has been handled.

We can set this up as an Outlook rule, but don't want this sitting on the client. We want this sitting on the gmail mail server.

I have tried to use filters which only seem to work on incoming mail.

Is this possible?