# How to add admin email in cc automatically for all user accounts in Google Apps for Business domain

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

I need to monitor all the users’ emails in my domain, so when a user in my domain sends a mail to others, my email (admin@abc.com) should be automatically added to cc.

I.e. if a person from accounts (acc@abc.com) sends an email then my id (admin@abc.com) should be automatically added and I need to receive the email. This should happen for all 30 accounts in my domain.

Comment: This appears to be closely related, if not a duplicate: [Autoforward outgoing mail in Gmail](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/27670)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this depending on the actual result you want.

1. [Google Vault.](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2462365?hl=en) Capture every email in your domain. Costs money.
2. [FlashPanel.](http://www.flashpanel.com/) Add the monitor the email. Some features free, some cost money.
3. In new control panel: Google Apps > Settings for Gmail > Advanced Settings > Sending routing. Free. See here: https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2368131

Answer (score 0):

How does this work:
"In new control panel: Google Apps > Settings for Gmail > Advanced Settings > Sending routing"

Comment: It would be helpful to add a little more info here. You've shown @Venny where to go, but how does this help? What does he do now that he's there?

Answer (score -1):

look into a contact management system. Many hook into email systems so that when an email is sent to a contact that is noted in the database. This allows the users of the system see the emails sent to that customer, and the replies. It also allows you to search by sender, contact, date, and even customer meta data (all customers that use product X that attended training in the last year)