# How can one set up a filter to forward automatically all outgoing Gmail messages?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email-forwarding

I have been able to set up an automatic forward of all incoming Gmail, but for outgoing I set up a filter, and it doesn't do anything. I need the forwarding to be automatic and discreet.

I am going to try the Gmail Auto-forward script.

Comment: Related-> [Autoforward outgoing mail in Gmail](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/27670/87130)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Gmail Auto-forward script](http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-forward-gmail-messages/20665/) bound to a Google Sheet. In Gmail, you create a filter that marks all matching emails with a filter. On the sheet side, specify that label name and the forward address and it will send them automatically.