# "Send mail as" not showing up in SENT folder

Tags: gmail

I have successfully setup **SEND MAIL AS in Gmail** for a number of different accounts but the problem is that the sent mail does not show up in the sent mail of the SEND MAIL AS email.

That is:

**Gmail account: mygmail@gmail.com**

**Yahoo account: TheYahoo@yahoo.com**

So when mygmail sends as TheYahoo, in the sent folder of TheYahoo there is not record of the sent mail. That is the same when I use GoDaddy or any other server.

Seems like Gmail just checks the SMTP credentials and sends it using it’s own servers. So the SEND MAIL AS server has no clue on what was sent in it’s name, whereby faking it.

What has been your guys experience in getting the mail in the sent folder? I need a backup in the other sent as folder.

Comment: If you send email using your Google mail account it isn't possible for the email to appear in your Yahoo account.  All you have done is change the header to indicate its being sent by the Yahoo account instead of the Google account.  It isn't actually being sent by Yahoo.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like exactly what should happen (and which Ramhound alludes to in [his comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79516/gmail-send-mail-as-not-showing-up-in-sent-folder#comment67128_79516)).

Yahoo Mail has no knowledge of the message you sent if it was sent by Gmail. All that "Send mail as" does is put a different sender on the message; it doesn't change where the message came from.

If you want a copy of the message to be in the other mailbox, you'll need to send the message to that mailbox directly. Putting your address in the `bcc` field will be perfect for that.

You might also find this useful: [Send a copy of outbound messages to another address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/send-a-copy-of-outbound-messages-to-another-address)