# Any way to see mail sent by other user through shared address?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

My wife and I have a "shared" email address, like `thesmiths@example.com` which we both use from Gmail when we both want to get replies or for signing up for certain websites.

When an email is received at that address, it gets forwarded to both of our personal Gmail accounts.

The problem is that when either one of us "sends as" that address, the other does not see the sent message. So we have to cc or bcc each other (and she usually forgets.)

Is there any automagic way to have those sent emails appear in BOTH of our Gmail accounts?

I've tried filters but I don't think they work on outgoing messages. Basically we want a filter that would automatically forward emails from that address to the other person.

I know this can be done with standalone mail clients, but neither of us uses those.

Comment: Short of having your wife's account [automatically cc your account or the shared account with _every_ outgoing message](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/send-a-copy-of-outbound-messages-to-another-address), I don't think that this is possible. (Even that option isn't possible with just Gmail.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, filters don't work on outgoing messages, only incoming.

Perhaps some of the alternative solutions offered on this question ([Send a copy of outbound messages to another address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/24626/354)) will help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible from the Gmail web interface. What you can do is to forward incoming e-mail, something you already seem to be doing. You can, however, achieve that using an e-mail client, for example [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/).

You both can configure the same e-mail address using the *IMAP* protocol (that is important, you shouldn't use POP3 because the first who gets the message also downloads it and the other one would not see it).

In a client, you can configure your account to automatically send a CC or BCC to a different address; so you'd add hers and she would copy yours.

I'm gonna try to translate the terms to english because my Thunderbird is in spanish language, so hopely you find a similar term in your menus if you finally give it a try.

Once your account is configured, right-click your account and choose *Configuration*. At the right-bottom side you'll find a button called *Manage identities*, click on it.

[image]

Select your account and click on *Edit...*. Choose the *Copies and folders* tab and there you'll see two options for CC or BCC.

[image]

This way, you'd add a CC or BCC to your wife's personal address and so would do she to your account, this way, you'll always have a "copy" of any sent e-mail.

Comment: As I asked, I know this can be done with a standalone client. I want to do it only through Gmail web interface.

Answer (score -1):

Configure that account in both yours and your wife's client, and use that for sending and receiving mail. The email will then automatically end up in the right send items folder.

Comment: Not sure what you mean ... the account is already configured in both our Gmails in the "Send mail as" setting.

Comment: I mean, configure the email as inbox, so you also see the entire content of the mailbox. This will ensure that sending a mail will also save it into the sent items folder, and not in the sent items from your other email account.

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean. "configure the email as inbox" ? The question is if this is possible via Gmail webmail.

Comment: In that case, just login to the gmail webmail account and use it as your email. So no forwarding etc should be done unles you want them as notifications.

Comment: I still have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: You have 2 gmail accounts. One for yourself and one for both of you. Instead of login into your personal account, login to the combined account. Mail sent there will remain in there, thus everytime you or your wife logs into that account, the mail will be in the sent items.