# How can I automatically forward Gmail emails when a label is applied?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Within Gmail, is there any way to automatically forward an email when I apply a label?

Gmail filters appear to only work with new emails. For my needs, applying the label is a manual process after the email was received.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an [Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) solution. Save it, changing the label and  recipient, and [set a trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to run this function every 5 minutes.

It searches for threads with the given label that were created after the last time the script ran. In each, it forwards **the first message** to the given address.

```
function autoForward() {
  var label = 'forwardthis';
  var recipient = 'forward@gmail.com';
  var interval = 5;          //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:' + label + ' after:' + timeFrom);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].getMessages()[0].forward(recipient);  // only the 1st message
  }
}
```

I add some variations, replacing the line with "only the 1st message":

#### Forward every message in the thread

```
var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
  messages[j].forward(recipient);
}
```

#### Forward the last message in the thread

```
var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
messages[messages.length - 1].forward(recipient);
```

Comment: This is definitely a great step forward. I can see how this would possibly solve the problem, however, how would I prevent the script from forwarding the same message again and again. Also, what about old email that I wanted to forward?

Comment: The `after` parameter makes sure that the script only looks at the emails from the last 5 minutes, which is after the previous time it ran. As for old messages with that label, you can forward them by temporarily removing `' after:' + timeFrom` part, and running script manually once.

Comment: I modified this a little, and instead of using a date check, I created a label `ForwardThis` and a nested label `ForwardThis/Forwarded`. The script looks for any messages in `ForwardThis` and forwards them, and removes the `ForwardThis` label and applies the `ForwardThis/Forwarded` label. Lets me stage any messages, regardless of age, for forwarding. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @DaveMartorana Can you share your script? I would like to see an example.

Comment: @botenvouwer sure - I use a mac/iOS app called "Deliveries" to track packages, and it integrates with Amazon receipts. All other shipping notifications get forwarded to them for processing. Just so you know what's going on: https://gist.github.com/themartorana/5fe0c4543e46213686d22580fe47969f

Answer (score 4):

Update: [Support dropped due to Google's API change](https://help.ifttt.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020249393-Important-update-about-the-Gmail-service).

---

The 3rd-party service [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) (If This Then That) makes this possible. Use the first Gmail trigger "New email labeled...". It doesn't have to be a new email, just newly labeled. May take a bit to trigger.

Comment: I just tested it and it seems to work a treat.

Comment: Really worked for me, the applet link is https://ifttt.com/applets/214039p-auto-forward-mail-from-gmail
The only bad thing is it fowards a unique email for every reply of the original email, so big conversations can 'spam' your inbox a little. I don't solve it yet, but it seems like it's possible to configure. It worked fast for me.

Comment: @jards I tried and failed to address the trouble you described: I forwarded an email thread with 3 emails in total, and each individual email got forwarded individually when I applied the label. Could you clarify how to _possibly configure_ things properly? I find the IFTTT fields limited, as of telling "thread" apart from "individual emails."

Comment: this used to be a good solution, unfortunately IFTTT no longer supports gmail

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry. The only automation available in Gmail by itself is Gmail Filters, which act on messages as they arrive. There's nothing built-in to Gmail that allows something to happen when a label is added to a message (unless it's part of a filter acting on an incoming message).